# Navigation Controller - app crashes after 20 views pushed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPad app that has linear navigation with a Navigation Controller. I am pushing View Controllers one at a time with gestures. I also have a PopOverController menu that can push View Controllers. Trouble is, when I push more than 20 it crashes.

Do I have to manually remove View Controllers from the stack after I get above a certain number? I was under the impression that the Navigation Controller would remove hidden View Controllers automatically.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There will be something else wrong in your implementation somewhere, you aren't releasing enough objects and using up memory or you're doing something else thats causing a problem. It won't be the navigation controller at all. You may be out-stepping an array or something similar.

What error message do you get in the console?

Comment: The error I'm getting is: 2010-11-03 12:02:27.810 EliteDemo[504:207] Received memory warning. Level=1
Also, DidReceiveMemoryWarning suddenly is invoked in all current ViewControllers.

Comment: You should respond to these warnings in all your view controllers and release as much memory as possible.

Comment: Is it okay to get DidReceiveMemoryWarning as long as you release when you do? I don't usually have an NSLog in there, so in the past I haven't known when this was invoked. Thanks.

Comment: Are we sure that MemoryWarnings are the reason why it crashes ? It normally come to MemoryWarning Level2 before it does.  Could you provide the log ?

Comment: Yes, it may not have been the only problem. Now that I've cleaned it up I only get the didReceiveMemoryWarning after about 20 slides, but it never crashes.

Comment: BTW, I have seen in the docs that in SDk 3.0 and beyond you should only release memory in the viewDidUnload and not in the didReceiveMemoryWarning. I am working in 3.2 for iPad so will heed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allocating too much memory use the viewDidUnload to release objects you won't use while the view is not presented again. You can restore then in the viewDidLoad as well.

Comment: So basically all the objects that I release in the dealloc I release in the viewDidUnload?

Comment: I did this and the crashing stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try releasing all the controllers after you push them onto the stack and also try releasing the navigation controller. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I already release the controller. So you're suggesting the following?

Comment: SlidesViewController *svController = [[SlidesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlidesView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  
  [svController setCurrentLevel:[self currentLevel] + 1];
  [[self model]setSlideNum:[self currentLevel] + 1];
  [svController setRole:[self role]];

  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:svController animated:YES];  
  [svController release], svController = nil;
  [[self navigationController] release];

Comment: [[self navigationController] release]; Makes it mad.

Comment: Dont try releasing it manually..Try and add it into autorealease pool. Something like.

UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController"] autorelease];

Hope this Helps you.